# Google API - replaceText - long delay

Tags: javascript, delay, long-integer, drive

My question is related to **Google API**. I have written a script that saves **template Doc** files and replaces text based on data from **Spreadsheet**. I use function **replaceText**. At the end of action, the document is sent as pdf to the desired email. The problem is that instead of receiving a document with the replaced line, the received document is a template. At the same time, on Google Drive, I can see the files with replaced strings (but it takes time). It seems that the problem is **long time needed for the document to be saved on the drive**. I used 10 seconds sleep function before changing documents to pdf and sending, but without luck. From time to time, it happens that the altered document is sent, but it is quite random. Any ideas? How long does it take for the document to be saved on Google Drive? (The document is text, 4 pages long). Have anybody experienced a similar problem? I already know that it is not some trivial error of sending a template instead of altered document (I guess most people will sugest it).

Answer (score 0):

I did several experiments, and sleep was not helpful. In the end, I divided the function into two parts:
1. To alter files and save copies
2. To send those copies on designated emails.
Thus, I run the 1st script, wait until I see new files, and then start the second one to send emails.